# Why is the dot or period ('.') treated as numeric in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was working on a query and found that the ISNUMERIC function in SQL Server is returning 1 for the input '.'

Why would that happen? Why does SQL Server treat that as a numeric?

Am I missing something here?

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR = '.'
SELECT IsNumeric(@Input)
```

Comment: The code for `ISNUMERIC` is notoriously slapdash. `$`, `-` and even `$-.` are all considered "numeric" as well, despite none of them containing even a single digit (or necessarily being parseable as an instance of any numeric type).

Comment: I tend to avoid ISUMERIC.   Better/safer results with try_conver() or try_cast().  Take a peek at https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Great link! Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I know :( 
I wasted a couple of hours to figure where is the query going wrong! :|

Comment: As given on MSDN docs this is faulty function [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017]

Comment: @JeroenMostert - no, anything that causes `ISNUMERIC` to return `1` will be parsable by *at least one* of the numeric types. The problem is that it doesn't tell you which types would work. All of your examples (and the OPs) can be converted to `money`.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi - it's not "faulty". It does precisely what it's described as doing. The problem is that the question it provides an answer for is not one that can be put to practical use. Nobody wants to know whether a string can be converted to *any* of the numeric data types, which is what `ISNUMERIC` answers. They almost always care whether it can be converted to a *specific* type (or a smaller range of types than all numerics), but that was never `ISNUMERIC`s design.

Comment: try `SELECT ISNUMERIC('.' + 'e0');`

Answer (score 2):

From the **[docs online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017%5D)**:

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($). For a complete list of currency symbols...

For example:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(+)
```

Will return 1, So I suggest to use [TRY_PARSE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead.

You can read this [useful link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manub22/2013/12/23/use-new-try_parse-instead-of-isnumeric-sql-server-2012/) from MSDN blogs, and this one from [SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/) too.

Answer (score 0):

SQL implicit convert empty value to zero.

```
SELECT CAST('' as int)  
SELECT CAST('.' as money)
```

and

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(0) --> 1
SELECT ISNUMERIC(0.0) --> 1
```

But i don't know where is this in the documentation

[char and varchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Character expressions that are being converted to an exact numeric
>   data type must consist of digits, a decimal point, and an optional
>   plus (+) or minus (-). **Leading blanks are ignored**. Comma separators,
>   such as the thousands separator in 123,456.00, are not allowed in the
>   string.